# Эффект подпрыгивающего падения

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Как можно реализовать эффект подпрыгивающего падения (или как он правильно называется)

Когда, вот например, меню открывается до конца и создаётся впечатление, что оно бьется об нижний бортик и подпрыгивает.
Когда-то видел в книге (онлайн такой эффект) и не могу его найти.

P.S. [Вот на этом сайте](http://www.artuelle.com) левый блок (с портфолио) при прокрутке страницы подпрыгивает.

Постить код не надо, лучше где почитать или правильное название эффекта. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это называется [easing](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html).

Comment: спасибо огромное